# Checking the number of times an item occurs in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, dom, web-applications

This is my code:

```
<html> 
    <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
            <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <title>TNF FANTASY</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div class="total">
                <i><h4>Money Remaining: <br>{{total |currency}}</h4></i> <h4>{{playersSelected}}</h4>
            </div>

            <ul>  
                <li class="players" ng-repeat="player in players">
                    {{player.name}} <br> 
                    {{player.Team}} <br> 
                    {{player.price| currency}} <br>
                    {{player.position| uppercase }}
                    <br>
                    <button ng-click="buy($index)">buy</button>
                </li>
                </ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.playersSelected = "0/6";
            $scope.total = 50000000;

            // keep track of what was bought already
            $scope.history = [];
            $scope.denteries = [];
            $scope.players = [
              {name : "Yasin 'YB' Amusan", Team : "Industry", price: 8000000, position: 'forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Hassan 'Hasi' Akinyera", Team : "Industry", price: 5000000, position: 'defender', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Femi 'Fabio' Awoniyi", Team : "Industry", price: 9000000, position: 'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Deji 'Dej' Awoniyi", Team : "Industry", price: 7000000, position: 'forward',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Koye 'K10' Kekere-Ekun", Team : "Industry", price: 9000000, position:'midfielder', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Teni 'Teezee' Zacchaeus", Team : "Industry", price: 6000000, position:'hybrid', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Bolaji 'Boj' Odojukan", Team : "Industry", price: 7000000, position:'forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Ernest", Team : "Industry", price: 6000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png' },
              {name : "Fikayo 'Kyo' Etti", Team : "Industry", price: 8000000, position:'Defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Efe Tunde-Imoyo", Team : "Industry", price: 5000000, position:'defender', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Temi 'Forbes' Afolabi", Team : "VGC", price: 14000000, position:'forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Dami Etomi", Team : "VGC", price: 7000000, position:'defender', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Tomi 'Belg' Belgore", Team : "VGC", price: 8000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Tobi 'Staxx' Kasali", Team : "VGC", price: 9000000, position:'Hybrid', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Bobo", Team : "VGC", price: 9000000, position:'Hybrid', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Ola Adeyemi", Team : "VGC", price: 5000000, position:'defender', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Pekun 'Pyzzle' Odutola", Team : "VGC", price: 9000000, position:'Hybrid', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Oreva 'Revz' Amata", Team : "VGC", price: 11000000, position:'forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Tenny 'TK' Karim", Team : "YMFC", price: 5000000, position:'Forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Andy Inegbese", Team : "YMFC", price: 5000000, position:'Midfielder', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Donald 'DO' Ofik", Team : "YMFC", price: 7000000, position:'defender', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Zachy Mbadiwe", Team : "YMFC", price: 10000000, position:'Forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Emeke 'Mexxo'", Team : "YMFC", price: 6000000, position:'midfielder', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Ife 'I-Baxx Bakare", Team : "YMFC", price: 6000000, position:'midfielder', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Gabriel 'Gabby' Inegbese", Team : "YMFC", price: 8000000, position:'Hybrid',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Jimi Oyelola", Team : "YMFC", price: 5000000, position:'Forward', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Chad 'Chadea' Oyefolu", Team : "ChadFC", price: 5000000, position:'Forward',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Ekoh 'Starboy' Sagoe", Team : "ChadFC", price: 15000000, position:'midfielder',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Tomiwa 'JBET' Jaiyeola", Team : "ChadFC", price: 13000000, position:'Forward',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Lemar Chris", Team : "ChadFC", price: 9000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Olumide 'Olic' Williams", Team : "ChadFC", price: 7000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Leke 'LVD' Dokomu", Team : "ChadFC", price: 7000000, position:'midfielder',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Dola Awosika", Team : "ChadFC", price: 5000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Nehemiah 'Memphis'", Team : "ChadFC", price: 7000000, position:'midfielder',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Kola 'Skippo' Ayanwale", Team : "ChadFC", price: 10000000, position:'midfielder',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Milekan 'Mileks'", Team : "ChadFC", price: 7000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Lanre 'Lavigz' Vigo", Team : "ChadFC", price: 8000000, position:'hybrid', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Alfred 'Flyz' Obande", Team : "FBGFC", price: 6000000, position:'defender', image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Chuka 'Zingy' Azinge", Team : "FBGFC", price: 6000000, position:'hybrid',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Osobase 'Oso' OmoKhodion", Team : "FBGFC", price: 10000000, position:'midfielder',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Arnold Okuguni", Team : "FBGFC", price: 7000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Ikenna Mbadiwe", Team : "FBGFC", price: 6000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Moukhtar", Team : "FBGFC", price: 8000000, position:'forward',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Chinedu 'Anuxx' Anukwem", Team : "FBGFC", price: 8000000, position:'forward',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Tosan 'Mac' Wiltshere", Team : "FBGFC", price: 6000000, position:'defender',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'},
              {name : "Martin Agbaso", Team : "FBGFC", price: 5000000, position:'forward',image: src='http://res.cloudinary.com/deji/image/upload/v1489787662/blank_photo_mqvivv.png'} 
            ];

             $scope.buy = function(i) {
                var p = $scope.history.indexOf(i);

                if (p !== -1) { //if bought, cancel it
                    $scope.history.splice(p, 1);
                    $scope.total += $scope.players[i].price;
                    $scope.playersSelected = $scope.history.length + "/6";
                } else { //else add it to history
                    if ($scope.total < $scope.players[i].price) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $scope.history.push(i);
                    $scope.total -= $scope.players[i].price;
                    $scope.playersSelected = $scope.history.length + "/6";
                }
            };
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make each user only able to buy two players with the position "defender" or "hybrid", two players with the position "midfielder" or "hybrid", and two players with the position "forward" or "hybrid". This makes 6 players available to buy in total.

I have tried using indexOf but this would only reveal the positioning of selected players in the history array, and not the number of times a player with each position above is bought.

Is this something that can be done with Angular JS or is it too ambitious?

Comment: please add the relavant part to the question and have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: the relevant part is in the link i provided. Or did i misunderstand your comment.

Comment: @DejiCalebAwoniyi links will die over time and when the link you have provided will be broken, your question will become meaningless. I have edited your question to remedy the situation.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks Gotcha

Comment: Updated the code for spacing and legibility

Comment: @DejiCalebAwoniyi take a look at MDNs Array methods, especially the `Array.prototype.includes()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a helper function for that purpose:

```
function getOccurrences(array, item) {
    var occurrences = 0;
    for (var index in array) {
        if (array[index] === item) {
            occurrences++;
        }
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

EDIT:

Based on the things written in the comment section, I realized the code I have provided is not enough. So, let's change the function to this:

```
function getOccurrences(players, array, item, helper) {
    var occurrences = 0;
    for (var index in array) {
        if (((typeof helper === "function") && (helper(players, array[index], item))) || ((typeof helper !== "function") && (array[index] === item))) {
            occurrences++;
        }
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

We need a helper for this purpose, like this:

```
function myHelper(players, val, item) {
    return players[val] && (players[val].position === item);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
getOccurrences($scope.players, $scope.history, "defender", myHelper);
```

Comment: could i use the helper function to check the occurrences of a specific property of an object in a larger array?

Comment: @DejiCalebAwoniyi can you give me an example?

Comment: sure thing. For example, in my code you edited, you will notice that each player in the "$scope.players" array has a position. My question is how can I check the occurrence of the position "defender" in the "history" array. I hope this clears it up.

Comment: for some reason it didnt seem to work. Maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: @DejiCalebAwoniyi actually I have tested this in your code example provided in the link of the initial question and it worked. Can you edit your question, add your current code there and let me know about it here in the comment section?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what you mean. This is the link to my question with your functions added in : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDTQ3OW8R6K5

Comment: @DejiCalebAwoniyi there are two problems: 1. You call the function which will return a value, but do nothing with it and you have put the function call outside of scope. Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDTQA93L8QK0

Comment: hmm i see what you did there. It solves part of the problem but the other half of my problem was alerting the user only once the number of "defenders" exceeds 2. Ditto for when the number of midfielders  and forwards exceeds 2

Comment: @DejiCalebAwoniyi The solution is to simply write if (getOccurrences($scope.players, $scope.history, "defender", myHelper) > 2) alert("Some text"); instead of alert(getOccurrences($scope.players, $scope.history, "defender", myHelper));. However, you will need to show some effort in the future, as I am convinced that you would have been able to work out this detail on your own. You need to believe in yourself.

Comment: Arpas Thanks so much. I'll buckle down and grind it out next time. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DejiCalebAwoniyi you are welcome. I wish you the best of luck for your projects.